# Setting up Xdebug for VSCode on Windows problem: steps are grayed out

Tags: php, windows, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I have used the XDebug wizard to download the `XDebug.dll`, I have linked it in php.ini and added the enable and autostart lines, I have installed the XDebugextension in `VSCODE`. I have added the system variable XDEBUGCONFIG with idekey=VSCODE.

When I start the debug with "Listen for XDebug" the debug control bar appears, but breakpoints are never reached, and controls for Step Over, Step Into, Step Out are greyed out.

Xdebug installed: 2.6.1

PHP Version: 7.2.12

Configuration File: C:\php\php.ini

> php.ini:

```
zend_extension = php_xdebug-2.6.1-7.2-vc15-nts-x86_64.dll
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
```

> launch.json:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Listen for XDebug",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9000
    },
    {
        "name": "Launch currently open script",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "port": 9000
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this line in your launch.json XDebug configuration:

```
"localSourceRoot": "http://127.0.0.1/(your public html folder)/"
```

Otherwise try closing your opened files, backup+delete your .vscode folder, and re-open VSCode.

Comment: localSourceRoot is deprecated, pathMappings is its replacement,but I get the same problem anyway ( I tried both ${workspaceFolder} and absolute path)

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to update your config to include a `pathMappings` block similar to the one below;

```
"pathMappings": {
    "/var/www/mc-dev/workflow/_src/": "${workspaceRoot}/_src/",
    "/var/www/mc-dev/workflow/_preview/": "${workspaceRoot}/_preview/",
    "/var/www/mc-dev/workflow": "${workspaceRoot}",
}
```

It might not be the intended function but I found you have to map each source directory in the project, in the example above this project will not debug if I use just `${workspaceRoot}` I have to map my `_source` and `_preview` development directories.

If you find that it is still not working I would try enabling the `"stopOnEntry"` param, just in case you're conditionally missing a breakpoint.

I would also take a moment and update your example config to include what you tried for path mappings so we can rule that out.